# How to handle a NULL response in an Ajax Server-Side Call: .done(function(data){..} never activated

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

Suppose I do an Ajax server-side call from jQuery e.g.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/myapp/fetchUser?username=" + username, 
        type : "get",
        dataType : "json",
        data : ''
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Server-side, in Java the `fetchUser` mapping fetches a JSON-serialized `UserT` object from the DB which may exist or be NULL. If the object exists I drop into `.done(function(data) {..}` successfully. But if the object returned is NULL, I **don't** drop into my JS code in `.done(function(data) ..)`.

How can I handle the NULL response in jQuery? The flow just stops right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataType : "json",` says the request **must** return valid json, even if it is just `{}`.  Either change your endpoint to always return valid json, or take that option off of your ajax request and parse the response if it exists.

The `done` does not happen because jQuery is trying to parse the null, getting an error, and going to the error callback.

Comment: thanks that worked. After removing `dataType : "json"` I started getting `""` (a blank str) for NULLs which I can check. Very tricky though!